# applying a string of commands to properties of an object in php

Tags: php

I've got a Accounts class which looks like this:

```
class Account {
public $accID;
public $balance;
public function __construct($accNum, $startBalance){
    $this->accID = $accNum;
    $this->balance = $startBalance;
}
public function deposit($amount){
    $this->balance = $balance + $amount;
}
public function withdraw($amount){
    if($amount > $this->balance)
        die("There is not enough money in this account to withdraw");
    $this->balance = $balance + $amount;
}
public function getbalance() {
    return $this->balance;
}
public function getaccID() {
    return $this->accID;
}
public function setaccID($accID){
    $this->accID = $accID;
}
}
```

This is fine, however I am inputting from a text file which deals with transactions. Example: "105 D 200" which means go to account 105 and Deposit 200.
I have been able to create multiple Accounts and split the transaction file into their different parts.

```
foreach($getFile as $v) {
list($c, $d, $e) = explode(" ", $v);
$acc[] = $c;
$type[] = $d;
$amount[] = $e;
}
```

I just cannot figure out how to use these sub strings in order work with my functions in the accounts class.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks you!

Comment: You have a logic problem in `deposit` and `withdrawal` because you're using `$balance` and not `$this->balance`

Comment: Why do you store your information in three unlinked arrays? Couldn't you just execute the desired actions directly inside the loop(switch on the command char) or atleast grouped together in a single array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , there is a logic error in your **withdraw** method, you are adding an amount and not subtracting it from the balance,

You can create some kind of Account Manager , which will store all accounts and you can get the account from it,delete,get all accounts ... etc

Then you can read file and process it.
Overall code would be something like this.

```
    foreach($getFile as $v) {
        list($c, $d, $e) = explode(' ', $v);
        $account = AccountManager::manager()->getAccountWithId($c);
        if($d == 'D') {
            $account->deposit($e);
        }
        // add more cases when to withdraw ... etc
    }

    print_r(AccountManager::manager()->getAccounts());

    // This will be a Singleton
    class AccountManager {

        private static $instance;

        private $accounts;

        protected function __construct() {
            $this->accounts = Array();
        }

        // To create a single instance
        public static function manager() {

            if(AccountManager::$manager === null) {
                AccountManager::$manager = new AccountManager();
            }

            return AccountManager::$manager;
        }

        public getAccountWithId($accountId,$autoCreate = true) {
            if(array_key_exists($accountId,$this->accounts)) {
                return $this->accounts[$accountId];
            } else if($autoCreate) {
                // Create a new account with zero balance
                $account = new Account($accountId,0);
                $this->accounts[$accountId] = $account;
                return $account;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public deleteAccountWithId($accountId) {
            if(array_key_exists($accountId,$this->accounts)) {
                unset($this->accounts[$accountId]);
            }
        }

        public getAccounts() {
            return array_values($this->accounts);
        }

    }


    class Account {
        public $accID;
        public $balance;
        public function __construct($accNum, $startBalance){
            $this->accID = $accNum;
            $this->balance = $startBalance;
        }
        public function deposit($amount){
            $this->balance += $amount;
        }
        public function withdraw($amount){
            if($amount > $this->balance) {
                die("There is not enough money in this account to withdraw");
            }


            // Make sure you are substracting the amount and not adding it.
            $this->balance -= $amount;
        }
        public function getbalance() {
            return $this->balance;
        }
        public function getaccID() {
            return $this->accID;
        }
        public function setaccID($accID){
            $this->accID = $accID;
        }
    }
```